# If I want to add an extra DC motor to an existing 6 V system, should I replace the battery with a higher current one?

Tags: batteries, current, motor

I purchased a used ride-on child vehicle (like powerwheels). It wasn't as great of a deal as I expected because it was 1-wheel drive, and it doesn't hold a charge that long, even when it isn't operated.

I recently opened the battery compartment and found the 6 V battery all bloated. It is a 4.5 A battery.

Since I'm ordering stuff to fix this car, I decided to get a second drive motor for the other rear wheel also.

Do I just get a 9 A+, 6 V battery so that it can properly provide current for both motors? I also thought about increasing the voltage to get better torque, but I'm not sure the current motor and the wire harness could handle it.

Comment: Two motor will run with different speeds and the toy will be uncontrolled.  Two motors drive is not simple task.

Comment: is the battery parameter  `4.5 A`, or is it `4.5 Ah`? .... same with the 9A+

Answer (score 1):

I have a freebie kid's tractor that had two 12V motors that could be connected series or parallel for low and high speed. Both motors ran but drew way too much current, and I could not see any way to fix them so I bought two new motors. You should probably buy a pair so they are matched.

Most batteries are rated in Ampere-hours (A-h). The motors will draw current depending on the torque, while speed will be proportional to voltage. You don't need to get a battery with higher capacity, but it would probably be better to install the largest size that will easily fit.

I doubt that this toy vehicle has a sophisticated controller, but if so, it should be able to control two motors in parallel. The total current would be about the same as a single motor if the torque is the same, but the maximum torque and locked rotor current for two in parallel will be double. If your vehicle is similar to mine, it will have a thermal breaker that will trip on overcurrent, and will reset in a minute or so.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion**:
What I have done in the past was to **upgrade/overhaul** the toy vehicle **to use a 12V battery** (check space - the larger, the better) while **using a control for selected maximum voltage (speed) and limited current** - see ahead.
I did *not* upgrade the drive train (motor), just the battery and made a **DIY speed/torque control**.

---

About other points you mentioned:

**#Motors: 1 (existing) or 2 (prospective).**
If you could fit 2 motors, and it does not cost you too much, you could use them, but as “PStechPaul” said, they should be equal characteristics = **either replace both motors or keep the single existing one**.
Spoiler: I would not concentrate the efforts there, but on the battery and controller.
Conceptually and on average, the vehicle would **consume about the same electrical power *for a given speed* with 1 or 2 motors** - power is lost as friction (soil, bearings, air) and electrical inefficiencies. The available mechanical power will be split by 2 motors, that would run cooler (split losses) if the final speed is reached at 12V, or not so much if running current is still high - depending on said frictions and required “mechanical power” (uphill).

**Motor Constants** - see [**Kv** and **Kt** here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_constants).
**Final speed** is dependent of **Kv** of the motor and battery voltage.
**Maximum torque** is dependent of **Kt** and running current.

**About Battery Capacity [Ah] and Voltage [V]**:
You hinted you may have more space to allow a larger battery.
A larger Ah battery also gives you lower internal resistance that contributes to higher torque, that is also limited by motor’s winding resistance.
So if you need more acceleration or “uphill” power, then higher current is the keyword, but the internal resistance of the motor and battery will give this maximum torque or not.
Surprisingly, **you can have higher torque increasing the voltage** because the final current usually is mainly limited by the motor winding and wiring resistances. So, the higher the voltage, the higher the current - and torque. The price is a higher power dissipation (**overheating**) and higher current. Such **overhaulings** outcomes should be properly anticipated and **verified**.
Recommended maximum current for ‘small’ SLA shall be limited to 3C. For a 4.5Ah, this means **battery’s sustained i_max < 15A**. See graphs provided the [picture #6 of this product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0889HJFMY) link (6V 4.5Ah).
If you use a higher capacity and same (6V 9Ah), you get mostly the same final speed, but longer running time.

---

**Controlling final speed with smooth torque**:
On-Off control may give a disturbing **kicking torque** from stop, which can be a cause of concern for smaller kids. An if you upgrade from 6V to 12V the starting kick will get worse.
For my nephews tricycle, I did a proportional speed “gas” foot pedal circuit based on LM317 and a potentiometer+trimpot as voltage divider (4~6x in parallel with 0.33R in series), upgrading to a more common 12V battery.  For the full throttle, a relay bypassed the LM317 bank, reaching full “12V” (or lower) speed and having a **controlled smooth torque** (at 8~12A) - each LM317 will allow up to 2A. A capacitor at the ADJ pin would give a smooth ramp-up, and a discharging diode a fast slow-down.

Doing this, their tricycle accelerated smoothly and the adults could limit (trimpot) its final speed - much safer playing time.